# Use list of inherited classes as parameter and return a dictionary of them

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I want to have a method that converts a list of a given type to a dictionary of that type, but I want the type to be a class inherited from my XMLData class, so that I can use the Name attribute as the key for the dictionary. 
Here's the code:

```
public static class SomeTools
{
public static Dictionary<string, XMLData> ConvertToDictionary(List<XMLData> xmlDataList)
{
    Dictionary<string, XMLData> dict = new Dictionary<string, XMLData>();
    foreach(XMLData data in xmlDataList)
    {
        dict.Add(data.Name, data);
    }
    return dict;
}
}
```

This works fine with getting just a dictionary of XMLData, but I can't use it to get a dictionary of LocationData. Here's the code that gets executed to try to retrieve location data.

```
List<LocationData> datalist = new List<LocationData>();
Dictionary<string, LocationData> locationData = SomeTools.ConvertToDictionary(datalist);
```

Comment: I would advise to go with generics. I'm on mobile so excuse any errors and typos: `public static Dictionary<string, TData> ConvertToDictionary<TData>(List<TData> xmlDataList) where TData: XMLData { ... }`. Also there is already a `ToDictionary` function in `linq` you can use to create the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit of trial and error with different approaches, I found one that worked.

This is my new code:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, XMLData> ConvertToDictionary<XMLData>(List<XMLData> xmlDataList)
{
    Dictionary<string, XMLData> dict = new Dictionary<string, XMLData>();
    foreach(XMLData data in xmlDataList)
    {
        dynamic d = data;
        dict.Add(d.Name, data);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

I don't know how I feel about the dynamic being in there, but it got things to work.

Comment: There is no need for dynamics here. And also this will not work if you call it with a lost of something that inherits from `XMLData` (though if you change it to `IEnumerable<XMLData> xmlDataList` it would work again)